Need help manually partitioning drive to install Ubuntu on 2014 MacBook Air
I am installing Ubuntu 24.04.1 from a USB drive on a 2014 MacBook Air, but I have encountered an issue at the manual partitioning screen where the Next button is grayed out. I successfully downloaded Ubuntu using balenaEtcher, and the MacBook boots from the USB drive, progressing through several installation screens until this point. If anyone has experienced this issue and resolved it, particularly by setting up the partitions correctly to enable the Next button, your assistance would be greatly appreciated.
I don’t see the Choose Installation Type section during the Ubuntu installation. Instead of being asked to select Erase disk and install Ubuntu or set up a dual boot, it skips directly to selecting language and keyboard layout, and then takes me to the manual partitioning screen.

I should have mentioned that I don’t see the “Choose Installation Type” section during the Ubuntu installation. Instead of being asked to select “Erase disk and install Ubuntu” or set up a dual-boot, it skips directly to selecting language and keyboard layout, and then takes me to the manual partitioning screen.

Make sure drive is gpt and you have an ESP -efi system partition , if new drive. If older drive use Mac to shrink some partition to make unallocated space.

Try the following.
Start a Live Ubuntu session
The upload is complete.
Open a terminal.
Run on it:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gparted
sudo gparted

From Gparted, select the disk and create a new gpt partition table and the following partitions:
One 1 gb boot-efi or bios-grub, depending on how your PC boots
One 100 gigs, ext4 for /
One   8 gigs, swap for Swap
One of the remaining gigs, ext4 for /home
Apply the changes
Start the installation and in partitioning choose manual.
And select the partitions for / and for /home, Grub is installed by default
